# How to quickly assess prospectiveness of a candidate based on his CV?

Tags: hiring-process, human-resources, hiring

I am working on a project for a dashboard and from UX perspective I would like a feature where HR managers could make a quick and rough estimate of a new candidate by giving him "marks" in certain fields like: Work experience, Knowledge of the field etc. so other users of the dashboard could later filter candidates in the table by average of all the marks. I would like to know if there are some universal metrics for quickly assessing how talented and worth hiring candidate is or any applicable ones, it doesn't have to necessary 100% precise, just a rough estimate of talent also it should be mostly things that can be found in CV as main part of users are sourcing specialist. I am looking for around 5-7 metrics. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to specify a position, and what skills you are looking for. Second, it is generally the interview where you can tell how skilled someone is, not the CV itself.

Comment: I think the HR managers are much better suited to answer this question, since hiring people (or, at least, disqualifying people from the hiring process) is a huge part of their job.

Comment: From a UX perspective I'd like an AI to do my job for me but that's unlikely to happen. Almost as unlikely is someone doing your job for you for free, which seems to be what you're asking for here. Even if algorithms like this existed they would be proprietary information.

Answer (score 5):

You can't judge talent from a CV. You can barely even judge talent from talking with people for a few hours. That's what makes hiring people so hard.

Also, if a universal metric existed, it would be gamed to the max by anyone looking for a job. It's half the reason people list buzzwords and technologies they once completed a tutorial for on their CV, because they know electronic systems are looking for those words.

Also also, "work experience" and "knowledge of the field" cannot be meaningfully condensed to a number. They are not scalars.

Answer (score 1):

Each dashboard would have to be constructed for each new position/opening. The people involved in running the team, screening the CV/resume/applications, and running the interviews would have to assign score ranges for each required and desired item they expect to see in the CV.  The users of the system would have to understand the criteria so they could filter the resumes accordingly.

They would have to know how to weigh the number of years using X technology VS years working a prestigious company Y vs a PHD at a place nobody has heard of.

The question would be how much time/effort would they put into the system before advertising the opening. My fear is that they would quickly use the defaults, or what was used for a similar position.

If I was assigned this task I would start by looking at the systems they already use to filter applications, ask the users if they work and then understand their strengths and shortfalls.

Answer (score 0):

CVs and Resumes are merely ad campaigns supplied by job applicants, and are little gauge of anything other than how well an applicant can write one.

There are no algorithms you can apply to any metrics that are going to accurately judge the actual talent of an individual.  We've had people who looked great on paper, but were terrible, and people who looked iffy on paper who were great once they came in on the interview.

At best, you could set up metrics for an individual position ranking a person on qualifications of the job based on categories of hard requirements, soft requirements and "nice to have" items and weight them accordingly, and anyone over a certain threshold gets an interview.

Beyond that, it's all alchemy.